# You have an error in your SQL syntax; ... near '[C@f8d6792'' at line 1

Tags: java, mysql, syntax-error

I can not figure out my syntax error with mysql.

I am running log in screen in a Java program in eclipse and get this error message:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near '[C@f8d6792'' at line
>   1

The 7 characters after `C@` change every time I run the program and the exception is thrown. I tried to look at the manual, but got discouraged after a while.

Here is my code for the section throwing the exception:

```
Connection conn = null;
String dbName = "test";
String serverip = "localhost";
String serverport = "3306";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverip + ":" + serverport + "/" + dbName;
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String databaseUserName = "root";
String databasePassword = "Pitbu!1s";
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
String sql = "select * from users where user_name = '" + textField_UserName.getText() + " AND password = '" + passwordField_Password.getPassword().toString() + "'";

try {
  Class.forName(driver);
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, databaseUserName, databasePassword);
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
  rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

  if (rs.next())

    lblUserName_Label.setText(textField_UserName.getText());
  lblUserNameOver_Label.setText(textField_UserName.getText() + "'s");
  textField_UserName.setText("");
  passwordField_Password.setText("");
  panel_Main.setVisible(true);
  panel_LogIn.setVisible(false);

  conn.close();
} catch (Exception i) {
  System.out.print(i);
}
```

Comment: I think maybe it is something in my database settings or server and not the code?

Comment: You missed ` for user name in the end.

Comment: Do not concatenation strings for SQL. Learn to use parameters from the start. It will save you a lot of trouble and head scratching, not to mention improve security.

Comment: Thank you Sudha. I can't believe it was that simple. tired eyes i guess. Thank you again. Sami, that is good advice. Thanks for the learning opportunity.

Comment: **WARNING**: When composing SQL queries it’s important to [properly escape](http://bobby-tables.com/java) any and all user-data to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). This code exposes you to severe risk and should not be deployed.

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use plain-text passwords. You *must* at the absolute least use a password-specific hashing method like something based on [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Comment: `passwordField_Password.getPassword()` seems to return `char[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss an apostrophe in your SQL statement

```
String sql = "select * from users where user_name = '" + textField_UserName.getText() + "' AND password = '" + passwordField_Password.getPassword().toString() + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is here:

```
String sql = "select * from users where user_name = '" + textField_UserName.getText() + " AND password = '" + passwordField_Password.getPassword().toString() + "'";
                                                                                         ^
```

You're not closing your quotes for userName and most likely this query is built:

```
select * from users where user_name = 'tom AND password='pw';
                                          ^
```

To make this work you can just add missing quotation and that's it.

A better way would be to not concatenate strings and use parameters to build your query. This is going to be more secure and easier to maintain.

Comment: I think there other half of the problem is that getPassword() returns a char[], and the toString of that is _not_ a String containing those chars. Hopefully using SQL parameters will good that, I'm not sure though.